# control plane pods in restart loop after installation with kube-adm

Tags: kubernetes

I tried to install k8s for the first time using kube-adm, as described in the getting started guide

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/

`kubeadm init`

finishes without errors and I can use kubectl commands to look around the shiny new cluster, e.g.

`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

gives me pods for for coredns, etcd, apiserver, controller-manager, kube-proxy, scheduler.

But after a minute or so, some of these pods get torn down and restarted. In particular also etcd and apiserver, so kubectl only works intermittently from then on.

```
$kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE     NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
kube-system   coredns-787d4945fb-mptkz        1/1     Running   3 (4m50s ago)   11m

kube-system   coredns-787d4945fb-r248b        1/1     Running   4 (73s ago)     11m

kube-system   etcd-mango                      1/1     Running   18 (4m1s ago)   13m

kube-system   kube-apiserver-mango            0/1     Running   14 (12s ago)    13m

kube-system   kube-controller-manager-mango   1/1     Running   23 (38s ago)    13m

kube-system   kube-proxy-mlwc9                1/1     Running   14 (43s ago)    12m

kube-system   kube-scheduler-mango            1/1     Running   18 (74s ago)    13m
```

It's very mysterious to me what is going on here. Logs of the pods can be found here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/117293

but I think these are not particularly enlightening.

I don't know how to go on from here. Any advice how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue, and it turned out containerd was misconfigured. The `SystemdCgroup` setting wasn't getting applied. You can check this by running:

```
containerd config dump | grep SystemdCgroup
```

Since you're using systemd (as I was), this needs to be set to true. However, setting up the config file as described in the [Kubernetes container runtime install docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#containerd-systemd) didn't seem to be properly setting the value.

What I was missing is that I needed to first generate a baseline config with:

```
containerd config default > /etc/containerd/config.toml
```

and then edit the `SystemdCgroup` setting in that file.

After doing that, the problem you described stopped occurring for me.